# php form submission for phpmailer to send mail using jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have read many answers here and tried almost every but non of them helped me the problem is I want to send contact from data to phpmailer which will send the mail. I want to do it with jquery ajax. Email is going perfectly but the problem is my form redirects to the "action" . I tried preventDefault(); and return false; but it didn't helped me.

I want to show user the message after successful form submission.
**here is my form code I am using bootstrap**

```
     <form class="form-horizontal" action="sections/contactdata.php" method="post" id="contact-us-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                   <!-- Name input-->
                      <div class="form-group">
                       <div class="col-md-12">
                             <input id="name" name="name" type="text"    placeholder="Your Name"
                               class="form-control input-md">
                         </div>
                     </div>

                     <!-- Email input-->
                     <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <input id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="Your Email"
                               class="form-control input-md">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- phone input-->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <input id="phone" name="phone" type="text" placeholder="Phone"
                               class="form-control input-md">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Textarea -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <textarea class="form-control" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Message"
                                  rows="6"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <!-- Button -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-4 pull-right">

                        <input type="submit" name="singlebutton" class="btn btn-success" value="SEND" id="singlebutton">
                    </div>
                </div>


            </form>
```

**my jquery ajax code**

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function (){
        $("#singlebutton").click(function(event)
       {
           /* stop form from submitting normally */
            event.preventDefault();

            /* get some values from elements on the page: */
            var $form = $( this ),
               $submit = $form.find( 'input[type="submit"]' ),
            name_value = $form.find( 'input[name="name"]' ).val(),
            phone_value = $form.find( 'input[name="phone"]' ).val(),

            email_value = $form.find( 'input[name="email"]' ).val(),
            message_value = $form.find( 'textarea[name="message"]' ).val(),
            url = $form.attr('action');

        /* Send the data using post */
        var posting = $.post( url, {
            name: name_value,
            email: email_value,
            phone: phone_value,
            message: message_value
        });

        posting.done(function( data )
        {
            /* Put the results in a div */
            $( "#contactResponse" ).html(data);

            /* Change the button text. */
            $submit.text('Sent, Thank you');

            /* Disable the button. */
            $submit.attr("disabled", true);
        });
        return false;
       });



   });

   </script>
```

**my php mailer code**

```
      <?php

  require_once '../assets/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

    if (isset($_POST['name'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['phone'], $_POST['message'])) {

    $fields = [

       'name' => $_POST['name'],
       'email' => $_POST['email'],
        'phone' => $_POST['phone'],
       'message' => $_POST['message']


       ];

      foreach ($fields as $field => $data) {

       }


     $m = new PHPMailer;

     $m->isSMTP();
     $m->SMTPAuth = true;
     $m->SMTPDebug = 1;
     $m->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
     $m->Username = 'myemail';
     $m->Password = 'mypassword';
     $m->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
     $m->Port = 465;

    $m->isHTML();

    $m->Subject = 'Contact Form submitted';



          $m->Body = 'From:' . $fields['name'] . '(' . $fields['email'] . ')'  . '<p><b>phone:</b><br/>' . $fields['phone'] . '</p>' . '<p><b>Message</b><br/>' . $fields['message'] . '</p>';


         $m->FromName = 'Contact';





       $m->AddAddress('rjsnh1522@gmail.com', 'Pawan');

      if ($m->send()) {

        //        header('Location: ../index.php');
          //        print_r($_POST);
         //        echo 'message send';
            echo "<h2>Thank you for your comment</h2>";
          //        die();
            } else {
              //        echo 'try again later';
              //        print_r($_POST);
           echo "<h2>Sorry, there has been an error</h2>";
                 }


    }
```

i get email every time i submit the form but it goes to the action page and the echo the text there. i want it to submit without reload and show user that form is submitted and i should get the email to.

I also tried using submit , on click but nothing helped me please tell me were I am doing it wrong.

please help me thank u.

Comment: Let's take a look at this article to send email - http://www.kvcodes.com/2014/01/how-to-create-contact-form-with-phpmailer-to-send-mails/

Answer (score 4):

**phpmailer code**

```
    <?php

  require_once '../assets/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

    if (isset($_POST['name'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['phone'], $_POST['message'])) {

   $fields = [

    'name' => $_POST['name'],
    'email' => $_POST['email'],
    'phone' => $_POST['phone'],
    'message' => $_POST['message']


];

foreach ($fields as $field => $data) {

}


$m = new PHPMailer;

$m->isSMTP();
$m->SMTPAuth = true;
$m->SMTPDebug = false;
$m->do_debug = 0;
$m->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$m->Username = 'your-password@gmail.com';
$m->Password = 'your-password';
$m->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$m->Port = 465;

$m->isHTML();

$m->Subject = 'Contact Form submitted';



  $m->Body = 'From:' . $fields['name'] . '(' . $fields['email'] . ')'  . '<p><b>phone:</b><br/>' . $fields['phone'] . '</p>' . '<p><b>Message</b><br/>' . $fields['message'] . '</p>';


   $m->FromName = 'Contact';





    $m->AddAddress('rjsnh1522@gmail.com', 'Pawan');

     if ($m->send()) {


        echo 'Thank You '.$_POST["name"].' We Will Contact You Soon franchise form';
       die();
    } else {
        echo 'try again later';
    }


 }
```

**my jquery ajax code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">



  $(document).ready(function(){

       $('#franchisedata').on('submit',function(){

          var that=$(this),
              url=that.attr('action'),
             type=that.attr('method'),
            data={};

        that.find('[name]').each(function(index,value){

            var that=$(this),
                name=that.attr('name'),
                value=that.val();


            data[name]=value;

        });

        $.ajax({

            url:url,
            type:type,
            data:data,
            success:function(response){

                console.log(response);
                alert(response);
            }


        });

        return false;

    });
});
  </script>
```

**the bootstrap form is the same as previously**